# how to Identify the cloud watch metrics for specific KCL in kinesis streams

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl

we have multiple kinesis consumer applications(KCL 2.0) are consuming the data from the same kinesis stream. All the consumer is sending the metrics to cloud watch and in the cloud watch those are showing up.

If i wanted to specifically understood and scale to multiple instances of one consumer application. how can we achive that... ?

cloud watch metrics `Get records iterator age`, `Incoming data - sum (Count)`

Answer (score 0):

KCL metrics are provided under separate namespace in cloudwatch. The namespace that is used to upload metrics is the applicationName that you provide in KCL configuration. So if you have multiple KCL application with differnt applicationName then, you will find those metrics in cloudwatch metric console under "custom namespaces"

complete list of KCL metrics can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/monitoring-with-kcl.html#kcl-metrics-list)